# How to adapt XVim to Xcode6.3.2?

Tags: xcode, plugins

I updated Xcode 6.3.2 then pull [XVim](https://github.com/XVimProject/XVim).
These is command I put,

```
cd XVim
git init
git checkout master
git pull
make
```

but my Xcode can't show XVim.
Someone knows why it?
I also tried to manual update(open XVim.xcodeproj and build) and failed.

My Info.plist's snapshot of UUID in /Users/myname/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XVim.xcplugin/Contents/

[image]

I hope your help, please.

Answer (score 2):

See my post on https://github.com/XVimProject/XVim/issues/757

---Here's the quote---

- Uninstall current XVim plugin completely. (`> make uninstall` should do it.)

  - Confirm you uninstalled XVim correctly (Run Xcode and confirm XVim is not there). 
    If you find XVim is not uninstalled, find the plugin and delete it. (maybe you can use `find` command to find XVim.xcplugin in your filesystem.)
  - Pull latest master branch.
  - Make it by `> make`
  - Run Xcode 6.3.2
  - Press "Load Bundle" button when Xcode shows dialog with a message "Unexpected code bundle..."
    If you don't see this dialog, try the following command and then restart Xcode.
    `> defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTPlugInManagerNonApplePlugIns-Xcode-6.3.2`